# Using flexslider to create a responsive, full width, fixed-height, carousel image-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a full width, fixed-height, carousel image-slider for the home page of a website that I'm working on.

That is, where the images are scaled to a fixed-height (matching the carousel height (the width doesn't matter)) which scales responsively as the page itself does.
However, I want my slider to be of lighter weight/ greater simplicity.

Here is my code thus far:

(here is the head)

```
<head>
<!-- Flex Slider API JS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: false,
            itemWidth: 360,
            itemMargin: 5,
            minItems: 2,
            maxItems: 4
        });
      });
    </script>
<!-- End of FlexsliderAPI JS -->
</head>
```

Here is the body:

```
<body>
    <!-- Placement of Flex Slider -->
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
              <img src="../../local/images/slide1.JPG" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="../../local/images/slide2.JPG"/>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="../../local/images/slide3.JPG" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="../../local/images/slide 5.jpg" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End placement of FlexSlider -->
</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.flex-container {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
}
background-color: red;
.flex-container ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.flex-container li {
list-style: outside none none;
display: inline;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
width: inherit;
max-height: inherit;
}
```

Thanks a ton for the help. - Cody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> not snapping to height bounds

I don't see anything in flexslider that does anything with the height. Make sure all the elements are the same height, either by creating similarly sized thumbnails or enforcing a height with CSS. You might need to remove the `itemWidth` configuration to avoid stretching.

> not displaying navigation

Your HTML is missing the navigation elements. I think you need to configure it; pass the navigation options:

```
controlNav: true,
directionNav: true,
prevText: "Previous",
nextText: "Next",
```

The configuration offercard uses is:

```
slideshowSpeed:7000,
animation:'slide',
controlNav:true,
directionNav:true,
pauseOnHover:true,
direction:'horizontal',
reverse:false,
animationSpeed:2000,
prevText:"&lt; PREV",
nextText:"NEXT &gt;",
easing:"linear",
slideshow:true,
itemWidth:800,
minItems:1,
itemMargin:0
```

Comment: That helps. I'm new to java-script, so understanding how each element effects the slide show is difficult. Sorry for the miscommunication about asking  the proper questions. I just thought they'd be assumed.